# Getting 2-factor Gmail authentication code from Sweden mobile number

Tags: gmail, passwords, multi-factor-auth

I have been facing a serious problem for many months. Usually I get a 2-factor authentication code from 51501 when I am supposed to log into Gmail. But for months I am getting a code from a Sweden-based mobile number: +46701327805. The first code I received from this number was in October 2015.

There is also a mobile number from USA that sometimes sends the code. I change my passwords every time this happens. What could be the possible reason for this and how to overcome this problem?

- By the way, I must say I have been hacked for years.
- I don't use VPN; my internet runs off a broadband modem.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about this: It's **HARD** faking SMSs and the outgoing number of 2FA SMS depends on the provider used - which varies. If you are *really* concerned, contact Google.